# Which set does this lego tree belong to?

Tags: part-identification

I thought this is part of a Modular house but it isn't ... I don't know which set does this "tree" belong to.

[image]
<sub>(click to enlarge)</sub>

Answer (score 6):

The stalk mold comes in two green versions [6097232: Stalk W. 1,5 Shaft And 3,2 Shaft](https://brickset.com/parts/6097232/stalk-w-1-5-shaft-and-3-2-shaft) and [6269940: Stalk W. 1,5 Shaft And 3,2 Shaft](https://brickset.com/parts/6269940/stalk-w-1-5-shaft-and-3-2-shaft)

Looking through photos of the sets containing these green parts, which contain some kind of tree build gives two sets:

- [10253-1: Big Ben](https://brickset.com/sets/10253-1/Big-Ben)
- [10247-1: Ferris Wheel](https://brickset.com/sets/10247-1/Ferris-Wheel)

It's not the Big Ben set as this set contain a small tree which is build using a 1x1 plate:

[image]

The Ferris Wheel has a similar tree as you have and it also contains the same white
[6170419: Stick 6M W/Flange](https://brickset.com/parts/6170419/stick-6m-w-flange) (white ring on your photo):

[image]

Only your tree is missing a second cone piece. So it is hard to tell if this tree is coming from the Ferris Wheel set or someone used that tree build to build their own.
[image]